# Why JavaScript file starts with (function (undefined)?

Tags: javascript, iife

I found some places people are writing JavaScript with starting function (undefined).Can I know why they are writing like this what is the advantage and disadvantage of using like this

```
(function(undefined) {
    /* some logic functions etc..*/
})();
```

Comment: Although the linked answers explains why, though I think there's no advantage to this approach. As per ECMAScript 5, undefined is not writable,configurable so its not an issue anymore in modern browsers even if its not strict..